# Get shop names at location android

Tags: android, geolocation

I am doing an android app for shopping users. I want to find the shop where the customer is in. I can get location name and premises names from latitude. But how to get the shop names in the current location? If there are multiple shops (like in a shopping mall) the application should able to show all the shops and let user choose.

Comment: Sharma I think you must use API I haven't deal with the geolocation but it should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to signup for google places API. Give the latLng to the API and you will get the nearby places.
2. Select the type of place you need:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

URL Example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=YourAPIKey